# Play Billing Library v3 Permission Denied Error?

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-play, play-billing-library

I am working on google Play Billing Library in my android project but still getting Permission denied Error I contacted to google play team they said there is no issue in api access , may be the error is coming from GCP .. so i have added many other permission to check either api is working or not but still getting permission deny.. Kotlin Android Code

```
    FirebaseFunctionsException.Code.PERMISSION_DENIED
```

this are the permission of Gcp

[image]

and  this operation is triggering permission error TypeScript Code

```
       static fromServiceAccount(playApiServiceAccount: any, firebaseApp: app.App): PlayBilling {

   //    Initialize Google Play Developer API client
     const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
     playApiServiceAccount.client_email,   //service account email
     null,
     playApiServiceAccount.private_key,    //service account private key
     ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'], // Auth scope for Play Developer API
     null
     );
     const playDeveloperApiClient = google.androidpublisher({
     version: 'v3',
    auth: jwtClient
    });


    return this.fromApiClient(playDeveloperApiClient, firebaseApp);
   }
```